# Does Internet Explorer 11 fix webdav/sharepoint mapping of a network drive that Internet Explorer 10 broke?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

IE 10 broke the webdav mapping in explorer that is extremely helpful with sharepoint document libraries.

With IE 11 in Win 8.1 - Does anyone know if this was fixed?